# InDirect Download Link From Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Want to give users, link to my files on server
but I dont want to get them direct link

I know how to do this (using rewrite or handler), I don't want how to
I need a library in C# that do this perfect 
thank you very much

Comment: What type of files and why?  If they are images you can encode them in base64

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Response.WriteFile("filePath")` in a button event for example.
Just make file name available for this method somehow (eg. querystring or reading from DB)
but bear in mind that `WriteFile` method doesn't support resuming so if your file is not big in size this method is useful.